# ejs with progress bar

Tags: node.js, ejs

How to define or update `style="width:<%=MettingPer %>;"` for progress bar in ejs

```html
<li class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
  Meeting
  <div class="progress">
    <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped bg-success  progress-bar-animated" role="progressbar" style="width: 75%;" aria-valuenow="25" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100">
      <%=MettingPer %>%</div>
  </div>
</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

EJS is rendered on the server, not the browser, so EJS has no idea what `document` is since that's something that's only defined in the browser.

So for this you need to load your page completely on the client side with zero value.

Then complete it according to the [instructions in JavaScript](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_progressbar.asp).

And as soon as you receive a response from the server, complete and hide it with a little delay.